# array of objects in SQL Stored Procedure 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a java webservice  which sends data in the following format in the wsdl and calls a SQL Stored Procedure to insert the record in SQL Database

```
<EmpID>2001</EmpID>
<EmpLOCN>US</EmpLOCN>
<Salary>
<Salaryamt>2000</Salaryamt>
<Salarytype>EU</Salarytype>
<TAX>
<Tax1>20</Tax1>
<Tax2>2</Tax2>
<TAX>
</Salary>
<Salary>
<Salaryamt>4000</Salaryamt>
<Salarytype>EU</Salarytype>
<TAX>
<Tax1>10</Tax1>
<TAX>
</Salary>
```

From the above input I want SQL to read this and insert 3 records with the same employee id

How do i read this in SQL and insert the records

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a 3rd row in your XML but here is how you can read that XML in TSQL:

```
    DECLARE @x XML

    SET @x = 
    '<EmpID>2001</EmpID>
    <EmpLOCN>US</EmpLOCN>
    <Salary>
        <Salaryamt>2000</Salaryamt>
        <Salarytype>EU</Salarytype>
        <TAX>
            <Tax1>20</Tax1>
            <Tax2>2</Tax2>
        </TAX>
    </Salary>
    <Salary>
        <Salaryamt>4000</Salaryamt>
        <Salarytype>EU</Salarytype>
        <TAX>
            <Tax1>10</Tax1>
        </TAX>
    </Salary>'


    SELECT
        Emp.Employee.value('(../EmpID)[1]', 'int') AS EmpID,
        Emp.Employee.value('(../EmpLOCN)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS EmpLOCN,
        Emp.Employee.value('(Salaryamt)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS SalaryAmt,
        Emp.Employee.value('(Salarytype)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS SalaryType,
        Emp.Employee.value('(TAX/Tax1)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Tax1,
        Emp.Employee.value('(TAX/Tax2)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Tax2
    FROM
        @x.nodes('/Salary') AS Emp(Employee)
```